# Can a use a 32bit guest Ubuntu Virtual Machine on a 64bit host machine in a Virtual Box?

Tags: virtualbox

Can I use a 32-bit guest Ubuntu Virtual Machine on a 64-bit host Windows Machine in a Virtual Box?? And can I use the binary which is compiled for 32-bit Ubuntu in 64-bit guest Ubuntu Virtual Machine??? I am trying to execute a 32-bit binary file in a 64-bit guest Ubuntu VM with 64-bit Host Windows in a VB but I am getting an error everytime which tells me `no such file or directory found` even when the binary file is in the same directory in which I am in. Is this because I am using a 32-bit binary in a 64-bit guest VM or it is because of any other reason?? And the folder in which the binary file is,that folder I have shared with my host windows machine.So is it any problem with sharing of folders??
I can't really make out what the problem is?? Please help
I have done ls -l and I got the following:-

```
raunak@raunak-VirtualBox:/media/base$ ls -l simg*

-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     278374 Sep 14 15:56 simg2img
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root       1947 Sep 15 17:39 simg2img.c
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root       2634 Sep 15 17:39 simg2simg.c
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root       5212 Sep 15 17:39 simg_dump.py
```

I also did more /proc/mounts and I got the following:-

```
    raunak@raunak-VirtualBox:/media/base$ more /proc/mounts

sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0

proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0

udev /dev devtmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,size=310192k,nr_inodes=77548,mode=755 0 0

devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0

tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=65892k,mode=755 0 0

/dev/sda1 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0

securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0

tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0

tmpfs /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0

tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0

cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,relea
se_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd 0 0

pstore /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0

cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,ne
t_cls,net_prio 0 0

cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_eve
nt 0 0

cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/memory cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory 0 0

cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/pids cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids 0 0

cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpu
acct 0 0

cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices 0 0

cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb 0 0

cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0

cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio 0 0

cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset 0 0

systemd-1 /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc autofs rw,relatime,fd=25,pgrp=1,timeout=0,min
proto=5,maxproto=5,direct 0 0

debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0

mqueue /dev/mqueue mqueue rw,relatime 0 0

hugetlbfs /dev/hugepages hugetlbfs rw,relatime 0 0

fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0

tmpfs /run/user/1000 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=65892k,mode=700,uid=100
0,gid=1000 0 0

gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=
1000,group_id=1000 0 0

/dev/sr0 /media/raunak/VBOXADDITIONS_5.1.6_110634 iso9660 ro,nosuid,nodev,relati
me,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500 0 0

/media/base /media/base vboxsf rw,nodev,relatime 0 0



    raunak@raunak-VirtualBox:/media/base$ file simg2img
simg2img: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, not stripped
```

Answer (score 3):

> Can a use a 32bit guest Ubuntu Virtual Machine on a 64bit host machine in a Virtual Box?

- Yes.
- The other way around also works but you then do need a 64-bit processor.
- you can not execute a 32-bit file on a 64-bit system (or the other way around) without installing support for it. It is called multi-arch.

> I am getting an error everytime which tells me no such file or directory found even when the binary file is in the same directory in which I am in

That, in general, means the file is not an executable.

- check with `ls -l` what the settings are for that file.

> So is it any problem with sharing of folders??

Executing from Microsoft filesystems is set when mounting the partition. So yes, this can be the cause.

- check the mount options for the partition with `more /proc/mounts`.

---

If you need more information edit your question with at the least the results of above to checks to do so we can expand this Q+A.

Comment: I have done ls -l & more /proc/mounts. and I have posted it's output in the question.I have checked and the binary file is executable.I have also run the following commands sudo chmod +x simg2img. But I am still unable to execute the binary file.Everytime I am getting an error which says no such file or directory found whenever I am trying to execute the binary file and run this command sudo ./simg2img system.img sys.raw. Whenever I run this command I get an error saying no such file or directory found. Please help. Is there any way to run the binary file in my current VBox with Ubuntu 16.04 a

Comment: can you do a `file simg2img` (check if it is a 32bit or 64bit program). I removed parts of the ls; all you needed to check was for that command ;)

Comment: Removed ls means?? Which command I needed to check??

Comment: see my edit on your question ;-) same goes for proc/mount all we need is the one line those files are on :)

Comment: Oh u mean to say that we only need the 4 files that are still there on ur edited ls. and I a

Comment: And which lines do we need for the proc/mount ?? Which 1 line?

Comment: So it means that the binary is executable if m not wrong

Comment: bottom one (/media/base)

Comment: Oh..it means that the folder is also shared properly if I am not wrong.

Comment: Then why I am not able to run it.The file is a 32-bit file type

Comment: good! have a search for multi-arch ;-) when that is there it should work. OR find a 64bit version of the command

Comment: Where do I search for multi-arch??

Comment: I have done file simg2img and I got this:-

Comment: raunak@raunak-VirtualBox:/media/base$ file simg2img
simg2img: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, not stripped

Comment: How to search for multi-arch???

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a 32 bit guest OS in a 64 bit OS.
But remember to use 64 bit guest OS in a 32 bit OS you'll need hardware that support 64 bit architecture.
Also don't forget to change your virtualization BIOS setting to yes.

Comment: I have obtained the output of the ls -l and more /proc/mounts. and I have posted it in the question.

Comment: I am still unable to run the command sudo ./simg2img system.img sys.raw

Comment: I have also done this sudo chmod +x /simg2img but I am still unable to run the binary file.Please help.

Comment: How do I change the virtualization BIOS setting to yes?